# ruby.split(/\n/) separate into multiple array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to Separate multiple Array entries with a newline. 
    the names in the aray value. Again I want to split the array like seperate names.
    Eg. names="alice\nbob"
    and I want names=alice&names=bob. How can I get that??

Comment: Neither `"alice\nbob"`, nor `names=alice&names=bob` looks like an array. Where is your array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
names="alice\nbob"
names = names.split("\n").map{|item| "names=#{item}"}.join("&")
#=> "names=alice&names=bob"
```

Answer (score 1):

If intention is to have it in form of query parameters, I will suggest using `Addressable::URI`:

```
require "addressable/uri"
def return_query(str)
  uri = Addressable::URI.new
  uri.query_values = {:names => str.split("\n") }
  uri.query
end

return_query("alice\nbob") #=> "names=alice&names=bob" 
return_query("alice in wonderland\nbob") #=> "names=alice%20in%20wonderland&names=bob"
return_query("alice&wonderland\nbob") #=> "names=alice%26wonderland&names=bob"
```